# Proving change of variables formula through riemann sums

Tags: calculus

How do we prove the change of variables formula in integration through riemann sums?I mean is it possible to take $\Delta u=f'(x)\Delta x$ and for small $\Delta x$ and then manipulate the sum taking limits?Please help by showing the proof.

Comment: Are you referring to integration by substitution?

Comment: Yes,the u substitution method